# How to split bulk video fast by using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a lot of videos, so I want to split them automatically. And they will be divided into 2 parts:

Part 1: 15 minutes
Part 2: the rest

This is code I have

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -t 00:15:00 -codec copy output1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00 -i input.mp4 -codec copy output2.mp4
```

However, I don't know how to split batch all video in 1 folder because I have a lot of file !

Searched a lot, but did not find. Please, help.

I use windows OS and I want to stream copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified Windows, so:

```
for %i in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%i" ...
```

If you are doing this in a batch file then use %%i instead of %i.

If you want to change the type of output file (eg. to MP4) then use "%~ni.mp4" as the output filename.

You should put %i in quotation marks so filename with spaces are handled correctly.